# Is there a way to grab an element by attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following custom tag/directive :

```
<tile class="ng-scope gridster-item" tilevalue="1" gridster-item="tile" row="0" col = "0" ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles"> </tile>
```

I wanted to set focus on this element. Is there a way to get an element by attribute name, so that I can set focus?

Comment: Setting focus on form element is understandable. You have custom element and and it has repeater applied on it, what do you have in this custom element?

Answer (score 0):

With plain javavascript you can use [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to get the elements you want, just like in CSS.

```
var element = document.querySelector('[class="ng-scope gridster-item"]')

var element = document.querySelector('[gridster-item="tile"]')
```

Then you are free to use whatever you want with `element`.

Answer (score 0):

as you tagged `jquery`, you have a lot of possibility, if there is only one element named "tile", you can use the element name `$("tile")`, or `$(".ng-scope.gridster-item")` based on classes.

Otherwise, use any attribute with `$("[attribute_name='attribute_value']")`

Note this can return an array of object. To get the element itself use `$("[attribute_name='attribute_value']")[0]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` (no jQuery required)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[gridster-item]");
```

or:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[gridster-item=tile]");
```

Set the focus:

```
elements[0].focus();
```

`querySelector` returns the first element, `querySelectorAll` returns an array-like `NodeList`.